# Cuda 4.0 vs 3.2

Tags: c++, c, comparison, cuda

Is CUDA 4.0 faster than 3.2?
I am not interested in the additions of CUDA 4.0 but rather in knowing if memory allocation and transfer will be faster if I used CUDA 4.0.
Thanks

Answer (score 7):

Memory allocation and transfer depend more (if not exclusively) on the hardware capabilities (more efficient pipelines, size of cache), not the version of CUDA.

Comment: This statement (7 votes and all) is quite misleading. There are significant platform dependencies on the speed of memory allocation; and on 64-bit, UVA-capable systems with multiple GPUs, pinned allocations on CUDA 4.0 will take longer because they are automatically portable  (i.e. mapped for all GPUs).

Comment: @ArchaeaSoftware Are you saying that CUDA 4.0 is producing less efficient code under the above setting *than CUDA 3.2*? If so, I’ll update; if not, then this is what my answer is already saying …

Comment: My comment was concerning memory allocation more than transfer performance.  Memory allocation performance depends more on the host platform and the CUDA implementation than the "hardware capabilities (more efficient pipelines, size of cache)." Because CUDA 4.0 made portable pinned memory the default on UVA-capable systems, allocating pinned memory absolutely is slower on multi-GPU systems.

Comment: @ArchaeaSoftware Point taken. But this is sufficiently different from my answer that I would prefer if you wrote your own answer (maybe just copy the comment). I’ll upvote it.

Answer (score 2):

Even while on CUDA 3.2, you can install the CUDA 4.0 drivers (270.x) -- drivers are backward compatible.  So you can test that apart from re-compiling your application.  It is true that there are driver-level optimizations that affect run-time performance.

While generally that has worked fine on Linux, I have noticed some hiccups on MacOSX.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, I have a fairly substantial application which ran ~10% faster once I switched from 3.2 to 4.0. This is without any code changes to take advantage of new features.

I also have a GTX480 if that matters any.

Note that the performance gains may be due to the fact that I'm using a newer version of dev drivers (installed automatically when you upgrade). I image nVidia may well be tweaking for CUDA performance the way they do for blockbuster games like Crysis.

Comment: aaah i c...so its better to uninstall all my drivers and cuda toolkit and sdk and reinstall the latest toolkit/sdk/drivers?

Comment: It might also be due to improvements in the `nvcc` compiler. Nvidia does that a lot.

Comment: Did you recompile the code, though? The compiler may use new functionality, even if you don't explicitly tell it to.

Comment: I did recompile but didn't change my code. At any rate, it's a pretty painless way to get some extra performance for free.

Answer (score 0):

Performance of memory allocation mostly depends on host platform (because the driver models differ) and driver implementation.  For large amounts of device memory, allocation performance is unlikely to vary from one CUDA version to the next; for smaller amounts (say less than 128K), policy changes in the driver suballocator may affect performance.

For pinned memory, CUDA 4.0 is a special case because it introduced some major policy changes on UVA-capable systems.  First of all, on initialization the driver does some huge virtual address reservations. Secondly, all pinned memory is portable, so must be mapped for every GPU in the system.

Performance of PCI Express transfers is mostly an artifact of the platform, and usually there is not much a developer can do to control it.  (For small CUDA memcpy's, driver overhead may vary from one CUDA version to another.) One issue is that on systems with multiple I/O hubs, nonlocal DMA accesses go across the HT/QPI link and so are much slower.  If you're targeting such systems, use NUMA APIs to steer memory allocations (and threads) onto the same CPU that the GPU is plugged into.

Answer (score -1):

The answer is Yes because CUDA 4.0 reduce the system memory usage and the CPU memcpy() overhead

Comment: Dumb question perhaps, but independent of the device's compute capability? That is, for all generations of hardware?